# Is there a good way to avoid anonymous functions in function prototypes?

Tags: javascript

I`m learning function constructor at the moment.
This seems to work fine.

```
Person.prototype.calculateAge = function () {
  console.log(2020 - this.yearOfBirth);
};
```

Linter doesn`t like when I use anonymous functions and offers arrow functions instead.
When I modify it:

```
Person.prototype.calculateAge = () => {
      console.log(2020 - this.yearOfBirth);
    };
```

I get NaN.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Arrow functions make poor class methods because they inherit the scope `this`, instead of pointing to the instance.

Comment: Is theres a good way to avoid anonymous functions in function prototypes??

Comment: No - and there's no real reason why you'd need them to be. They'll always be methods of the object's `prototype`.